# MultipartFormDataContent parsing

Tags: c#, request, httpclient

I'm trying to send a request to this using MultipartFormDataContent , but i want to upload a media in this request :

The original script is this one, but it's not working as it need the "test.png" to be sent from file :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://dezgo.p.rapidapi.com/image2image"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "X-RapidAPI-Key", "API_KEY" },
        { "X-RapidAPI-Host", "dezgo.p.rapidapi.com" },
    },
    Content = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        new StringContent("stablediffusion_1_5")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "model",
                }
            }
        },
        new StringContent("0.8")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "strength",
                }
            }
        },
        new StringContent("8")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "guidance",
                }
            }
        },
        new StringContent("change color to blue")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "prompt",
                }
            }
        },
        new StringContent("30")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "steps",
                }
            }
        },
        new StringContent("1")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "upscale",
                }
            }
        },
        new StringContent("dpm")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "sampler",
                }
            }
        },
        new StringContent("")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"),
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "init_image",
                    FileName = "test.png",
                }
            }
        },
    },
};
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
}
```

So, what i tried is to reconstruct the MultipartFormDataContent like this but it return Error 400 (Bad Request):

```
string filePath = "test.png";
var bytefile = AuthGetFileData(filePath);
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytefile);
fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();

formData.Add(new StringContent("stablediffusion_1_5"), new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data").Name = "model");
formData.Add(new StringContent("0.8"), new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data").Name = "strength");
formData.Add(new StringContent("8"), new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data").Name = "guidance");
formData.Add(new StringContent("a man"), new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data").Name = "prompt");
formData.Add(new StringContent("30"), new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data").Name = "steps");
formData.Add(new StringContent("1"), new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data").Name = "upscale");
formData.Add(new StringContent("dpm"), new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data").Name = "sampler");
formData.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytefile)), "init_image", "test.png");

var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://dezgo.p.rapidapi.com/image2image"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "X-RapidAPI-Key", "API_KEY" },
        { "X-RapidAPI-Host", "dezgo.p.rapidapi.com" },
    },
    Content = formData,
};

using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
}
```

Comment: Besides it returning 400 status code, does the response provide any error message?

Comment: 400 (Bad Request)